# RegeX in PHP to capture string

Tags: regex

How do I get the following values ​​in Regex from the following string

```
<tr><td>4 <td><b><a href="number.php?v=41a&k=53&t=102">3</a></b>

v = 41
k = 45
t = 102
```

I wanted only the number of each segment (v k t)

I tried this and got only one at a time

```
v=\d+
```

Comment: You want to extract those values individually or separately (3 regexs)?

Comment: If possible, in a single regex I wanted to extract the three

Comment: 1) use DOMDocument/DOMXPath to extract the href value. 2) use `parse_url` to extract the query part of the url. 3) use `parse_str` to get the different values.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input string is really as simple as you said, you could use preg_match_all:

```
$str = '<tr><td>4 <td><b><a href="number.php?v=41a&k=53&t=102">3</a></b>';
preg_match_all('/(?<=[vkt]=)\d+/', $str, $m);
print_r($m[0]);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 41
    [1] => 53
    [2] => 102
)
```

Comment: Better than I imagined

Comment: @André: Because it's a feature of preg_match_all, it isn't only a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Use positive lookbehind for each letter:

```
(?<=v=)\d+
(?<=k=)\d+
(?<=t=)\d+
```

Comment: Because each regex is for different value, when you concatenate them, they will be useless.

Comment: @André: regexr support only javascript regexes and lookbehind is  not supported by javascript regexes.

Comment: Well, it's actually a matter of opinion but generally regex101 is good.